# Setting Rewrite Rules for Zend Skeleton

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2, virtualhost, opensuse

I use an opensuse 12.2 os, apache 2.2, zend framework 2.
In order to have the skeleton app of the framework i set a virtual host in apache's files.
Here is definition

```
   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
       DocumentRoot "/home/gabriele/Web/zf2-tutorial/public/"
       ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
       SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development" 
       <Directory "/home/gabriele/Web/zf2-tutorial/public/">
             Options +FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             DirectoryIndex index.php 
             AllowOverride None
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

When i move to zf2-tutorial.localhost i can see the page of welcome.
I tried the htaccess

```
     Options +FollowSymlinks
     RewriteEngine On
     # The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
     # exists, simply serve it.
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
     RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
     RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

     The structure of my folder is :
     \home
           \gabriele 
                    \Web
                         \zf2-tutorial
                                     \public
                                            -index.php
                                            -htaccess
```

If i go on zf2-tutorial.localhost/test1234 i should see an error redirected inside the skeleton instead i see a normal apache error.

Comment: Did you restart apache after adding the vhost?

Answer (score 0):

You have got your VHOST setup incrrectly for starters:

```
  AllowOverride All
  DirectoryIndex index.php 
  AllowOverride None # WRONG - remove this.
```

You have got Overrides off, which will kill your htaccess.